# How can I use Vite env variables in vite.config.js?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vite

With the following `.env` in my Vite project:

```sh
# To prevent accidentally leaking env variables to the client, only
# variables prefixed with VITE_ are exposed to your Vite-processed code

VITE_NAME=Wheatgrass
VITE_PORT=8080
```

How can I use `VITE_PORT` in my `vite.config.js`?

Comment: You need to use VITE_APP_Name to define the variables in the ENV file.

Comment: Here's the documentation for that: https://vitejs.dev/config/#using-environment-variables-in-config

Answer (score 176, accepted):

You can load the `app level` env variables and add them to the `Node level` env variables:

```js
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';


export default ({ mode }) => {
    process.env = {...process.env, ...loadEnv(mode, process.cwd())};

    // import.meta.env.VITE_NAME available here with: process.env.VITE_NAME
    // import.meta.env.VITE_PORT available here with: process.env.VITE_PORT

    return defineConfig({
        plugins: [vue()],

        server: {
            port: parseInt(process.env.VITE_PORT),
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: If the above does not work for you (e.g. you want to import a variable that is not prefixed with `VITE_`. Try this: `process.env = { ...process.env, ...loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), '') };` The prefx (3rd argument) does make the difference here.

Comment: Regarding the `server.port` assignment, my `vite.config.ts` gives me the error "Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'".  How do I fix that?

Comment: @BrentArias Environment variables are always strings, but the type definitions for Vite expect a number there. Use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Comment: thanks it works in file `vite.config.ts`

Comment: CAUTION: Better use `Object.assign(process.env, loadEnv(mode, process.cwd()))` instead of destructuring `process.env`! When I added the env variables like that, the keys lost their case-insensitivity somehow (running on Windows). To be specific, running `npx vite` failed for me because `process.env.SYSTEMROOT` is undefined, while `process.env.SystemRoot` IS defined. This does not happen anymore when I use `Object.assign` instead.

Comment: CAUTION: setting vars in process.env seems to prevent the build process from setting them from their respective .env file (like .env.production) when the Vite build process runs after the fact.

If there's name collision, the variable is not replaced, i.e: API_URL was being set to localhost when building for prod.



My personal solution was to used a different variable to hold the loaded env, like `tmp_env` instead of `process.env`

Answer (score 10):

If the above solution by @matt doesnt work for you then change the `vite.config.ts`/ `vite.config.js` like below

*1st Solution*

```
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {

const env = loadEnv(
  'mock', 
  process.cwd(),
  '' 
)
  const processEnvValues = {
    'process.env': Object.entries(env).reduce(
      (prev, [key, val]) => {
        return {
          ...prev,
          [key]: val,
        }
      },
      {},
    )
  }

  return {
    plugins: [vue()],
    define: processEnvValues
  }
}
```

**2nd Solution**

```
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';


export default ({ mode }) => {
    process.env = Object.assign(process.env, loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), ''));

    return defineConfig({
        plugins: [vue()],
    });
}
```

Comment: Where can I place a console.log in order to see the values behind 'define'?

Comment: It should work after `processEnvVales` , if it not possible , I will check once

Comment: A console.log after does not print out any logs on the terminal nor in the webdeveloper console.

Comment: @ShadowGames you need to add it before the return statement.

Answer (score 6):

I had extactly same issue and found a soultion.

```
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd());

  const API_URL = `${env.VITE_API_URL ?? 'http://localhost:3000'}`;
  const PORT = `${env.VITE_PORT ?? '3000'}`;

  return {
    server: {
      proxy: {
        '/api': API_URL,
      },
      port: PORT,
    },
    build: {
      outDir: 'public',
    },
    plugins: [react()],
  };
});
```

In .env

```
VITE_API_URL='https://yourapiurl.com'
VITE_PORT=3000
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: shut it bot, the answer is clear - it just doesn't add much to the accepted one

Answer (score 5):

You can use dotenv

https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#readme

in your `vite.config.js`

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv'

dotenv.config()

process.env.YOUR_ENV_VAR
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are searching for a simpler solution, you can do something like this:

```js
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite';

const env = loadEnv(
    'all',
    process.cwd()
);

let port = env.VITE_PORT;
```

The `loadEnv` type signature is detailed below:

```js
function loadEnv(
  mode: string,
  envDir: string,
  prefixes: string | string[] = 'VITE_',
): Record<string, string>
```

By default, only env variables prefixed with `VITE_` are loaded unless `prefixes` is changed.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can be usefull for someone that is working with react and vite

**vite.config.js**

```
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
// export default defineConfig({
//   plugins: [react()],
// })

export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  const env = loadEnv("mock", process.cwd(), "");
  const processEnvValues = {
    "process.env": Object.entries(env).reduce((prev, [key, val]) => {
      console.log(key, val);
      return {
        ...prev,
        [key]: val,
      };
    }, {}),
  };

  return {
    plugins: [react()],
    define: processEnvValues,
  };
});
```

**How to TEST:**

1.- Add these variables to a new **.env** or **.env.local** file

```
REACT_APP_MAILCHIMP_URL="https://gmail.xxxx.com/subscribe/post"
REACT_APP_MAILCHIMP_U="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
REACT_APP_MAILCHIMP_ID="YYYYYYYYYYYY"
```

2.- Add a new component **component/Test.js** file

```
export const Test = () => {
  console.log(import.meta.env.REACT_APP_MAILCHIMP_URL); 
  console.log(import.meta.env.REACT_APP_MAILCHIMP_U); 
  console.log(import.meta.env.REACT_APP_MAILCHIMP_ID); 

  const a_var = `${process.env.REACT_APP_MAILCHIMP_URL}`;
  console.log(a_var);

  return (

    <div>
      <small> You are running this application in mode.: 
      <b>{process.env.NODE_ENV}</b>
      </small>

      <div>
        <small> REACT_APP_NOT_SECRET_CODE:  
        <b> {process.env.REACT_APP_MAILCHIMP_URL}</b>
        </small>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

3.- Add Test component to **App.js** file

```
import "./App.css";

import { Test } from "./components/Test";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Test />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Was going to write the same thing by myself, but here you are my friend, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is using the firebase project name based env files like .env.yourapp-prod and .env.yourapp.dev, you can bring those runtime vars into vite to make them available for builds like this:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { resolve } from 'path';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import fs from 'fs';

export default defineConfig(() => {
  // Decide which .env file to load based on the mode

  const envFile = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'env.yourapp-prod' :'.env.yourapp-dev';
  // Load the environment variables using dotenv and assign to process.env
  const envConfig = dotenv.parse(fs.readFileSync(envFile));
  process.env = { ...process.env, ...envConfig };

  // Convert environment variables for Vite's define option
  const envVarsForDefine = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(process.env).map(([key, value]) => [`process.env.${key}`, JSON.stringify(value)])
  );


  return {
    plugins: [sveltekit()],
    test: {
      include: ['src/**/*.{test,spec}.{js,ts}']
    },
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        $src: resolve('./src'),
        $stores: resolve('./src/lib/stores'),
        $assets: resolve('./src/assets'),
        $icon: resolve('./node_modules/svelte-bootstrap-icons/lib')
      }
    },
    define: envVarsForDefine
  };
});
```

Then deploy your app like this:

`NODE_ENV=staging firebase deploy`

or

`NODE_ENV=production firebase deploy`

Answer (score 1):

Anyone who is **using Vite 4.0** and `process.env = { ...process.env, ...loadEnv(mode, process.cwd()) };` **is not working** for you **try this**:

First Install `dotenv` using `yarn add dotenv`. Then go to your `vite.config.js` file write these:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

dotenv.config();

console.log("hello", process.env.VITE_HOMEPAGE_URL) //when you run the frontend using yarn dev you will be able to see this on you cmd to know this works! :D

export default defineConfig({
  base: process.env.VITE_HOMEPAGE_URL,
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

Your environment variable file `.env` should look something like this:

```
VITE_HOMEPAGE_URL=https://abc.something.com/home/
```

If you face linter error like `process is not defined` go to your `.eslintrc.cjs` file and add `node: true` inside the `env`. So it will look something like below

```
module.exports = {
  env: { browser: true, es2020: true, node: true },
  //...other settings
}
```