# import.meta.env works everywhere except vite.config.ts file

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, vite

I have created the react project using [vite](https://vitejs.dev/).

In vite `import.meta.env.VITE_SOME_RANDOM_ENV_VARIABLE` is used to access the env variables anywhere in our project.

For example in the **below code in line number 12.**

[image]

But my problem is, when i try to access env variables in my `vite.config.ts` file, i get the
following error.

```
Property 'env' does not exist on type 'ImportMeta'
```

I also added the image below to show error.

[image]

Can you please explain why behaviour is different in `vite.config.ts` file?
I am also adding the importMeta.d.ts file's code below for your reference.

[image]

***I got the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66389043/how-can-i-use-vite-env-variables-in-vite-config-js), but can you still explain why the behaviour is different in `vite.config.ts` file?***

Comment: Please refer to the vitejs config's environment variable [docs](https://vitejs.dev/config/#environment-variables)

Comment: Your answer can be found https://stackoverflow.com/a/66389044 and

Answer (score 10):

Put this at the top of your `vite.config.ts` file

```
/// <reference types="vite/client" />
```

Answer (score 7):

try this:

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["vite/client"]
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, did not work for me.
[This worked for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66389043/how-can-i-use-vite-env-variables-in-vite-config-js).

But still i don't know, why is thiis case with vite.config.ts

Comment: After adding this, I started to see many other type errors appear.  Ultimately I had to add `"types": ["vite/client", "@types/node"]` and it worked!

Comment: Be careful with this solution because you are overriding default types with whatever you specify in the array, which can lead to unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

Move your `vite-env.d.ts` file to the root.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including a detailed explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand while I do see your point here, I also feel that if someone doesn't understand why config files don't propagate backwards, I am really answering a whole bunch of other questions that weren't asked. I am not trying to be elitist here!

Comment: The question is about *vite.config.ts*, and you mention *vite-env.d.ts*; I don't understand how they are related..? If your solution does in fact solve the problem then it'd be incredibly important/ helpful to explain why it does OR link to some documentation that would allow others to understand. Otherwise all it does is add more confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're encountering is likely due to Vite not performing type-checking on TypeScript files by default.

When you add a reference to the Vite client types using the `/// <reference types="vite/client" />` directive, it provides type information solely for the Vite client and not for the entirety of your Vite configuration.
If you'd like TypeScript to include all the type definitions from the `@types/*` packages located in your `node_modules`, you can simply omit the types field from the `compilerOptions` in your `tsconfig.json``.

By default, TypeScript includes the `./node_modules/@types` folder in the `typeRoots` option. Therefore, you needn't add it explicitly unless you've altered the default configuration.

If you prefer not to specify the `types` and `typeRoots` in your `tsconfig` file to benefit from automatic type inclusion, but also wish to add Vite client types, then you can utilise the include option in your `tsconfig` file. This approach prevents hardcoded `types` and `typeRoots` configuration, includes all types automatically, and appends the Vite client on top. For this, you might try:

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
"compilerOptions" : { ... },
"include": [ …, "vite.config.ts"]
}
```