# How can I conditionally apply a plugin in Vite depending on build type?

Tags: ionic-framework, vite, ionic-react

I am using Vite to build an [Ionic React app](https://ionicframework.com/docs/react), which has three versions:

- iOS
- Android
- PWA

I'm using [vite-plugin-compression2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-compression2?activeTab=versions) to gzip the PWA files.

Here's my `vite.config.ts`:

```
  plugins: [
    eslint(),
    compression({
      algorithm: 'gzip',
      exclude: [/\.(br)$ /, /\.(gz)$/],
    }),
    // Deleting the originals will break the PWA because index.html gets deleted.
    compression({
      algorithm: 'brotliCompress',
      exclude: [/\.(br)$ /, /\.(gz)$/],
      deleteOriginalAssets: false,
    }),
```

The problem is that this compression breaks my Android build, because Android's `gradle` attempts to compress the already compressed files, which gives a `duplicate resources` error and aborts the build.

So I want to apply the compression plugin for the PWA and iOS, but not for Android.  How can I do that?

The [Vite documentation describes conditional application of plugins for build/serve](https://vitejs.dev/guide/using-plugins.html#conditional-application), but I need conditional application for two different ways to build.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by adding an environmental variable, `VITE_BUILD_PWA`.

```
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default ({ mode }) => {
  // Make Vite env vars available.
  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/66389044
  process.env = { ...process.env, ...loadEnv(mode, process.cwd()) };
  const isEnvBuildPwa = () => process.env.VITE_BUILD_PWA === 'true';

  return defineConfig({
    build: {
        // All the build config.
      },
    },
    plugins: [
      eslint(),
      isEnvBuildPwa() && compression({
        algorithm: 'gzip',
        exclude: [/\.(br)$ /, /\.(gz)$/],
      }),
      // Deleting the originals will break the PWA because index.html gets deleted.
      isEnvBuildPwa() && compression({
        algorithm: 'brotliCompress',
        exclude: [/\.(br)$ /, /\.(gz)$/],
        deleteOriginalAssets: false,
      }),
    ],
  });
};
```