# import.meta.env undefined in Vite with Laravel

Tags: laravel, environment-variables, vite

I'm using Laravel 9 with Vite. The documentation says that to access .env variables I can use import.meta.env but when I try to use this variable in my vite.config.js I get the message 'undefined'.
My .env file contains VITE_ prefixed vars. I tried to access them and other vars but import.meta.env is still empty.
I tried to ensure that I was using ESM format to ensure this vars are available but nothing changed.
I managed to access my environment vars using process.env but its not what the documentation says.

Can someone explain this to me please ?

Answer (score 0):

I also recently encountered this problem, there are 2 solutions

1. if vite 2 ver or more (https://stackoverflow.com/a/66389044/10085537)

> ```
> import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite'
> import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin'
>
> export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
>     process.env = {...process.env, ...loadEnv(mode, process.cwd())}
>     return {
>         plugins: [
>             laravel({
>                 input: ['resources/app.js', 'resources/app.css']
>             }),
>         ],
>         server: {
>             host: env.VITE_DB_HOST,
>             hmr: JSON.stringify(env.VITE_ASSET_URL),
>             port: env.VITE_DB_PORT,
>         },
>     }
> })
> ```

2. if you have a version less than 2 (maybe lower). Found it on the Internet,
   may be needed ***import path from 'path'***

> ```
> function getEnv() {
>     const envFilePath = path.resolve(__dirname, './.env')
>     try {
>         let res = {}
>         const data = fs.readFileSync(envFilePath, 'utf8')
>
>         data.split('\n').forEach((kv) => {
>             const [key, value] = kv.replace(/\s*/g, '').split('=')
>             if (key && value) {
>                 res[key] = value
>             }
>         })
>
>         return res
>     } catch (err) {
>         console.error(err)
>     }
> }
>
> const envs = getEnv()
> console.log(envs.VITE_DB_PORT, envs.VITE_ASSET_URL, envs.VITE_DB_HOST)
> ```