# vite - import.meta.env undefined error in laravel 10

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, vite

I'm embarking on a new project with Laravel 10 and need to use the APP_URL env variable in the vite.config.js file. Following is the file variable defined in .env file

```
VITE_APP_URL="${APP_URL}"
```

The vite.config.js file is

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
    server: {
        https: false,
        host: true,
        hmr: {host: import.meta.env.APP_URL, protocol: 'ws'},
    }
});
```

But vite server is failing to restart with following error.

```
10:41:55 AM [vite] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'APP_URL')
10:41:55 AM [vite] server restart failed
```

I even tried to log the value of `import.meta.env` but this also logs `undefined`.
After some research I created `tsconfig.json` file and added following in the file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["vite/client"]
    }
  }
}
```

But still I'm getting the same result. Is there anything additional I need to do to use the env variables in `vite.config.js`

**EDIT**
I'm using vue2 with vite

Could it be something to do with `tsconfig.json` file? Like vite not using/reading `tsconfig.json`

Comment: Actually I already followed the instructions  in the thread. But it didn't resolved the issue

Comment: i think you should loud you`r env file to use it in config you can see this solution:
[How can I use Vite env variables in vite.config.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66389043/how-can-i-use-vite-env-variables-in-vite-config-js)
or this page: 
[Using Environment Variables in Config](https://main.vitejs.dev/config/)

Comment: another problems is: 
1- you defined variable with name `VITE_APP_URL` but calling `APP_URL` 
2- and i think you didnt enable **typescript** on your project because your config file has _.js_ format.